# Blank page after installing dpaste in a django site. What is the issue?

Tags: python, django

This is my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <div style="width:50%; marginleft:25%;">
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
```

I installed dpaste according to the their docs. Now, when I go to the link 127.0.0.1:8000/mypaste a blank screen shows up.

I'm guessing there is something wrong with my base.html but not sure what. I might be completely wrong too.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML source of the blank screen?

Comment: Erm. Its my base.html. The base.html of dpaste is extending the base.html of my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [template](https://github.com/bartTC/django-paste/blob/master/dpaste/templates/dpaste/snippet_details.html), it doesn't use block "main", it uses "extrahead", "title", "headline", "content", "sidebar" and "script_footer" blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you moved the templates from the [dpaste/templates](https://github.com/bartTC/django-paste/tree/master/dpaste/templates/dpaste) folder into your own project's template folder (i.e. TEMPLATE_DIRS in your settings)?

Comment: My file hierarchy is like this: mysite/templates/dpaste/{html files}

Answer (score 1):

Given your base.html, if `{% block main %}{% endblock %}` is not replaced with anything, you would get a blank page. My guess would that that is the case. What should be going in that block? Are you sure the block name is correct?

Comment: Base.html should contain the skeleton of the site, right? Thus, I've given a very basic skeleton into which the code would be interjected. I'm assuming that the code is not getting interjected because of nothing is coming inside the block. What changes should I do to get it working?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/bartTC/django-paste/blob/master/dpaste/templates/dpaste/snippet_details.html. dpaste uses a block named "content" for the main content. It also has other blocks defined in there such as "sidebar" and "extrahead" that you'll need to include in your base.html.